# jquery trigger event on match of element on page load

Tags: jquery, function, triggers

I've created a custom jQuery function and I want to call it for every match of an element on the page when it loads. The syntax I'm using to call the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.class1.class2").fixClassesForIE6("a","b");
});
```

That syntax does nothing. The `fixClassesForIE6` function is never called.

I think I maybe need to use 'trigger' in some form? But I'm not entirely sure.

Ultimately, I want:

1. the page to load
2. find all DIV elements on the page with *class1* and *class2*
3. Trigger my function for each match

Comment: Have you created this function as a plugin?

Comment: What object is `fixClassesForIE6` member of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `fixClassesForIE6` using the [plugin syntax](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.fn.extend), and all should be good:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        fixClassesForIE6: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                // plugin logic goes here
            })
        }
    })
}(jQuery);
```

If you've done that and it's not working, then you've got problematic code elsewhere.

Comment: Well, I'm a dope. I didn't actually post the code I was using to delcare my function. Well, in the interim, I managed to figure things out. I ended up using this syntax:

$.fn.$.fn.fixClassesForIE6 = function(myVar1, myVar2){
...my logic...
};

And it seems to work! I assume the plug in syntax might be a bit verbose if one doesn't need it to be a plugin? (That said, for what I'm doing, this might make more sense as a plugin anyways...)

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 possible problems:

1) Your selector is wrong.  You can confirm this by executing your selector, by itself, in a JavaScript debugger, such as FireBug for Firefox.

2) The method fixClassesForIE6() ... is that your method?  I do not recognize it as a JQuery method.  If it is your method, then this will not work - because you are calling it on the results of the selector, which don't have that method.  Instead, try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var elements = $("div.class1.class2");
    elements.each(function(){ fixClassesForIE6(this, "a","b"); });
}
```

Comment: Hmm...sorry, YES, that was my own method. I completely omitted that. 

Here's where I ended up and this seems to be working: 

$.fn.fixClassesForIE6 = function(class1, class2){
  alert("function called!");
};

$(document).ready(function() {

 $("div.class1.class2").fixClassesForIE6("","");

}); 

If I run that, it will pop up an alert for each and every DIV on have on the page with both classes 'class1' and 'class2'.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting all DIV elements on the page with class1 and class2, I think that you should use 
$("div.class1,div.class2") instead.

For doing something for each matching div w/ class1 or class 2, i think that you can use the each() function here?

```
$("div.class1,div.class2").each(
     function(index){
       //do something here
     });
```

Comment: I'm guessing DA is looking for elements that have both of those classes, not different elements that have either class.

Comment: ScottE: agreed. `.class1.class2` is perfectly valid for this.

Comment: Indeed, I'm looking for BOTH classes. Hence the 'fixIE6' part of the function name. You can't attach CSS using double-class names in IE6, so I'm creating a jQuery script to fix that.